# 96 Impreza ECU Pinout

Tags: subaru, wiring, electronic-control-module, impreza

I'm still working on getting this EG33 into a 96 Impreza. I have received some wiring harness diagrams, but am unable to match them to the ECU which is in the car. I'm wondering if what I have are the correct diagrams. Here is what the ECU, connector, and plug looks like:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have the following wiring diagrams, which are supposed to be for the 96 Impreza. I'm not seeing how it marries up to the above connections:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

If someone could help me rectify the plug to the diagram, that'd be awesome. Or, if I have the wrong diagram, it'd be awesome to get the correct ones. And before you ask, I was unable to match a colored wire to something on the plug. Specifically I was looking at wire 32 on the ECU (or could be ECM per what's on the diagram). It shows to be LgB, which could either be light brown or light blue. I couldn't match this with a corner pin on the connector anywhere. At least I'm assuming it should be on a corner somewhere due to where it's at in the diagram.

Comment: ***I don't have a solution, but I do admire your problem.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wiring diagram looks correct when comparing against another wiring diagram. I only did a cursory look over comparing random pin colors. Pin 32 should be Light Green/Black.

This may be easier to read... for the 2.2.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How does the ECM connector numbers align with what I'm showing you in the picture above? I see four lines of pins on what I'm showing you and only two lines of connections in what you're showing me. Even worse in my diagrams, lol. And yes, the Impreza is a 2.2L (EJ22) originally.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 What do you mean by align? Wire Color/Pin Identification? Without being able to see the back with the wires spread It's hard to say but usually if you're looking at the harness connector pin one is top left of the connector (tabs facing up). You could also look for the first and last wire on the connector. In this case #1 being yellow and white being #96. It looks like your connector is also split into 2 portions left being 1-48 and right being 49-96 or I could be wrong and it's one portion 1-96.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Actually by counting the pins and blank spaces (tab facing up) you can see that pin 1 is the top left the first 2 column set and continues left to right with the next row being 17-44, 44 being blue/white.

Comment: I can confirm, sir, you are correct! Pins 1&2 both have Yellow/Green wires. Pin 16 has the Blue/Red wires on it. Those are across the top which shows I have the connector upside down in the picture if starting with pin 1 being in the upper left position (as you are looking face on at the connector). The top line is 1-16 as you are suggesting in your second comment. Thanks for the info ... this helps a lot as well as the wiring chart being a lot clearer to understand.